# How do I add/remove form fields dynamically?

Tags: entities, 8, ajax

i have form build in standard like:

```
public function getFormId() { }
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { }
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { }
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { }
```

in my build form it return $form array with button add and remove.

if i press add, i would like to add new textfield above the add button (or anywhere else)

and next to the new text field i like to have a minus button ( - ) to remove the text field.

how do i achieve this in drupal 8 with ajax? how do i position the newly added textfield? how do i generate the field id (`$form['composition']['DynamicallyAddedAndRemove']`)?

i know how to build ajax callback but im not sure how to add new field and/or remove it dynamically through ajax

this is what i did and it didn't work, any idea why

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct($coreService) { }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) { }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() { return 'id_form'; }

  /**
   * Overrides Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormController::form().
   *
   * Builds the entity add/edit form.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   An associative array containing the current state of the form.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An associative array containing the settings add/edit form.
   */   
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  /*
   * to make it short... $form build here
   * then continue...
   */

    // Initialize the counter if it hasn't been set.
    if (null !== ($form_state->get('fields'))) {
      // Nested this deep to avoid conflicts with other modules
      $form_state->set('fields', array(
        'module' => array(
          'fieldset' => array(
            'items_count' => 0
          )
        )
      ));
    }

    $max = $max = $form_state->get(['fields','module','fieldset','items_count']);

    $form['fields']['module']['fieldset'] = array(
      '#type' => 'details',
      '#title' => t('title here'),
      '#description' => t('description here'),
      '#open' => TRUE,
    );

    // Add elements that don't already exist
    for ($delta = 0; $delta <= $max; $delta++) {
      if (!isset($form['fieldset'][$delta])) {
        $element = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title' => t('tittle 00'),'#required' => FALSE);
        $form['fieldset'][$delta]['t00'] = $element;
        $element = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title' => t('title 01'),'#required' => FALSE);
        $form['fieldset'][$delta]['t01'] = $element;
        $element = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title' => t('title 02'),'#required' => FALSE);
        $form['fieldset'][$delta]['t02'] = $element;
      }
    }

    $form['fieldset']['add'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'add',
      '#value' => t('Add field'),
      '#submit' => array(array($this, 'addSubmit')),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => array($this, 'addfield'),
        'wrapper' => 'foo-replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );


    return $form;
  }

  /**
    * Ajax submit to add new ingredient.
  */
  public function addSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $max = $form_state->get(['fields','module','fieldset','items_count']);
    $form_state->set(['fields','module','fieldset','items_count'],$max++);
    $form_state->set('rebuild', TRUE);
  }

  /**
    * Ajax callback to add new ingredient.
  */
  public function addfield(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['fieldset'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Display result.
  }

}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {        
  $form['fields']['modules'] = array(
      '#type' => 'details',
      '#open' => TRUE,
      '#title' => t('sample field'),
      '#description' => t('Explaination about sample field is here, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. bla yadda bla yadda. this is a very long description here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. bla yadda bla yadda. this is a very long description here.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. bla yadda bla yadda. this is a very long description here.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. bla yadda bla yadda. this is a very long description here.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. bla yadda bla yadda. this is a very long description here.thank you.'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="modules-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    $max = $form_state->get('fields_count');
    if(is_null($max)) {
      $max = 0;
      $form_state->set('fields_count', $max);
    }

    // Add elements that don't already exist
    for($delta=0; $delta<=$max; $delta++) {
      if (!isset($form['fields']['modules'][$delta])) {
        $element = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('field Name'),
            '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'route here',
        );
        $form['fields']['modules'][$delta]['iqqq'] = $element;
        $element = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title' => t('aaa'),'#required' => FALSE);
        $form['fields']['modules'][$delta]['iaaa'] = $element;
        $element = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title' => t('sss'),'#required' => FALSE, '#suffix' => '<hr />');
        $form['fields']['modules'][$delta]['isss'] = $element;
      }
    }

    $form['fields']['modules']['add'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'addfield',
      '#value' => t('Add more field'),
      '#submit' => array(array($this, 'addfieldsubmit')),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => array($this, 'addfieldCallback'),
        'wrapper' => 'modules-wrapper',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit sample'),
    );


    return $form;
  }

  /**
    * Ajax submit to add new field.
    */
  public function addfieldsubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    $max = $form_state->get('fields_count') + 1;
    $form_state->set('fields_count',$max);
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }

  /**
    * Ajax callback to add new field.
    */
  public function addfieldCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    return $form['fields']['modules'];
  }
```

Comment: I get an Uncaught AjaxError when using this code.

Comment: Hi , how it can apply to a content type form ? will it be applicable ?

Comment: You should add a description of why this works and what fixed it. Don't just post a block of code as an answer.